# Manually Invoking email verification

Tags: django-allauth

We've been using django-allauth for quite some time now in production. We can enable account email verification which works great. But we now have a REST api that allows users to register through the API and the workflow doesn't go through django-allauth. Is it possible to manually invoke the django-allauth email verification feature or do we need to use a custom solution?

Answer (score 6):

I'll just post my answer here as I've been searching for adding email verification with Django Built-in Authentication (And using a Custom Auth Model), I used the method mentioned by Marcus, I'll just add all the other stuff around it for anyone who wants to do the same.

**First:** Install django-allauth as described [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

**Second:** Add your email configurations in the `settings.py` file :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' #I used gmail in my case
EMAIL_HOST_USER = <Your Email>
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = <Your Password>
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = <Default Sender name and email>
```

**Third:** Add configurations for verification and default login url, you'll find the documentation of all config parameters [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), note that in my example I'm using a custom user model as mentioned, that's why I'm setting `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` to `True` & `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD` and `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED` to `False`, also the `LOGIN_URL`,`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL` and`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` parameters are used after the user clicks on the confirmation link sent by email to him

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION='mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
LOGIN_URL='app:login_user'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='app:login_user'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL='app:login_user'
```

**Fourth:** After your signup form, save the user instance with `is_active` parameter set to `False`, then call the method:

```
from allauth.account.utils import *
send_email_confirmation(request, user, True)
```

**Finally:** Receive the signal after the user confirms his email, and set `is_active` to `True`

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Signal sent to activate user upon confirmation
@receiver(email_confirmed)
def email_confirmed_(request, email_address, **kwargs):
    user = MyUser.objects.get(email=email_address.email)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
```

Finally, you would want to change the default site name from Django Admin as it will be included in the email sent.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the solution I've found was to call the original `send_email_confirmation` method from allauth. I am using DRF3 for my API.

```
from allauth.account.utils import send_email_confirmation

...
def some_view(request):
    user = ...
    ...
    #using request._request to avoid TypeError on change made in DRF3 (from HTTPRequest to Request object)
    send_email_confirmation(request._request, user)
    ...
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I'll give that a try!

Comment: I get an error with this "You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties". I am using Token authentication with rest-auth, and a React front end. This seems to be incompatible with allauth, which expects CSRF tokens from a template. Any idea how to call send_email_confirmation from an SPA frontend?